# Angularjs double ng-repeat data shown from back to front, Why?

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat, double

I have two confused points in my code,

First One,
This is my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover" my-element="docu">
```

I used the double ng-repeat, but the data shown from back to the front. How to fix this?

Angularjs file:

This is the data:

```
$scope.people = [
    {'name':1,'des':'nice','age':12},
    {'name':2,'des':'good','age':13}
  ];
..........
.directive('myElement', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      items: '=myElement'
    },
    restrict: 'EAC',
    template: '<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ><td ng-repeat="p in item">{{p}}</td></tr>'
  };
});
```

The result:

```
12  nice    1
13  good    2
```

The result should be like this:

```
1   nice    12
3   good    13
```

Second One,

I used ng-if to check the data's length, if there's no data, the table's body shown this "Upload the file". But this sentence always shows up the table head. I don't know why. How to fix this?

HTML:

```
<tbody my-element="people">      
            <span ng-if="people.length == 0">Upload the file</span>
        </tbody>
```

My result(if there's no data):

```
Upload the file
Name    Des Age
```

The result should be like this:

```
Name    Des Age
Upload the file
```

The link is my code, please check it:

http://codepen.io/AceSai/pen/ZbEExN?editors=101

Comment: If you have two questions, you should make separate posts. For your first issue though, an object's keys are not guaranteed to be in any specific order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Answer**

I guess the syntax of second ng-repeat should be **(key, value) in obj**.

Basically when angular perform ng-repeat on objects's key it sorted the keys alphabetically that is the reason your output is not expected.

So if you see.
your Output :

age des    name

12  nice    1

13  good    2

Is that makes sense.

To overcome this you can iterate array and use object.propertyName.

I din't get your **Second question**.
I am suspecting there are html ordering issue. Just explain second issue more.

Comment: Hey, can you give me an example of object.propertyName?

Comment: Hi CId, You can check other answer for object.propertyName example. Angular has removed sorting feature from 1.4+ version. So you can try that too. Here is the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 0):

since you have an array of objects, that means that `item` is an object and not an array, so I really don't understand why do you expect to get it in the order you want.
however, you can simply do only 1 `ng-repeat` like this:

```
template: '<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ><td>{{item.name}}</td><td>{{item.des}}</td><td>{{item.age}}</td></tr>'
```

Comment: Cause I tried to do a table using custom directive, and the table's head and table's body show dynamic. No matter what table datas give me, I can show them. If you use {{item.name}}, {{item.des}},{{item.age}} in my directive template, I can't use it for different tables any more. Like my table data has 4 rows, not 3, how do you show it?